# How do sum a column when using group by in SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, mariadb

I am new to SQL and I have this table right here using this query:

```
select 
    shop_name, sum(sales) as 'total_sales',
    concat((sum(sales)/10250) * 100, '%') as 'sales_percentage' 
from pos 
group by shop_name;
```

Output:

```
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| shop_name | total_sales | sales_percentage |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
| shop1     |        3250 | 31.7100%         |
| shop2     |        3750 | 36.5900%         |
| shop3     |        3250 | 31.7100%         |
+-----------+-------------+------------------+
```

I achieved this by cheating, I added the total sales myself (which was 10250) but I wanted to know how am I going to get the sum of the total_sales while using the group by (since I can easily output 10250 just by using sum(sales) if I haven't used group by)

Thank you in advance

[Picture of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HczXs.png)

Answer (score 1):

Use window fun tions:

```
select shop_name, sum(sales) as total_sales,
       concat((sum(sales)/sum(sum(sales) over ()) * 100, '%') as sales_percentage
from pos 
group by shop_name;
```

Note that I removed the single quotes from the column aliases.  Most importantly, they are not needed.  But as a matter of practice, do not confuse string literals with column aliases; they are different and using single quotes for the aliases is unnecessary (use backticks or double quotes to escape the names if necessary).

Comment: May I know what exactly happened here? Sorry, I am just a student and we still haven't got to that.

Comment: @DaveIsraelGundiao . . . The function is a handy way of calculating the total sum over all the rows.  You can refer to the documentation in MariaDB for window functions to start learning about them.